# How to move your rake tasks to the rails lib dir from in a gem generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

Im creating a custom gem and have some rake files that need to be installed into the users /lib/tasks directory to work.  I want create a generator that will move / create my rake tasks in the tasks directory so they can use them.

Does anyone have any idea how do to this in a custom gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your gemspec includes the tasks

and then in your Rakefile

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need require your rake file in your Rakefile of your root project.

Comment: I can't.  My rake file calls active record and since AR is not in the ruby gem, it throws and error.  This is why I want to dynamically create the rake file and move it in the rails app.